# Getting app configuration from sqlite database in PHP

Tags: php, database, sqlite, configuration

I have an sqlite database with a *config* table with 3 rows: id, config and value.

I'd like to get the settings in this table in variables: how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a documentation how to use SQLite with PHP:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php

Edit: On the site you can see how it works

```
<?php
$dbhandle = sqlite_open('sqlitedb');
$query = sqlite_query($dbhandle, 'SELECT name, email FROM users LIMIT 25');
while ($entry = sqlite_fetch_array($query, SQLITE_ASSOC)) {
    echo 'Name: ' . $entry['name'] . '  E-mail: ' . $entry['email'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, I already read that doc but `$database['link'] = new SQLiteDatabase($database['uri']); $query = 'SELECT setting, value FROM config'; $result = $database['link']->arrayQuery($query); echo $result['name']` in example doesn't work. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Do you get some errors? And what is you $database['uri']? Have you enabled you error reporting to get some errors?

Comment: `$database['uri']` is where che sqlite database is located. When I try to print out `$result['name']` I obtain... what? A few of minutes ago I obtained nothing. However, now I obtain `turlandob`, two values, but whithout any space. How can I divide and put them in variables?

Comment: With $query->fetch(SQLITE_ASSOC) in a while loop here is the documentation: http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-fetch-array.php

Comment: `$query = 'SELECT setting, value FROM config';
//$result = $database['link']->arrayQuery($query);
$result = $database['link']->unbufferedQuery($query);
while ( $row = $result->fetch(SQLITE_ASSOC) ) {
 echo $row['name'];
}`
I obtain `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /membri/turlando/site/includes/init.php on line 18`. Line 18 is `while ( $row = $result->fetch(SQLITE_ASSOC) ) {`

Comment: you have used the object oriented example. I have edited my post with an example. @turlando